# Module not found - Importing svgs in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, next.js, babeljs

I'm using the `inline-react-svg` plugin with babel in order to import inline SVG in NextJS.

That's my `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    "inline-react-svg",
    [
      "import", {
        "libraryName": "antd",
        "style": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

And also, I had to declare the modules related to image extensions because I'm using TypeScript.

That's the modules declared inside the `@types` folder in the root of the project

```
declare module '*.png'
declare module '*.jpg'
declare module '*.jpeg'
declare module '*.gif'
declare module '*.svg'
```

But I'm not able to import any SVG file because TypeScript can't find the module.

[image]

[image]

Doesn't work with absolute imports but it works with the relative path `"../../public/images/icons/go-back-arrow.svg"`

Comment: check this https://medium.com/anna-coding/how-to-import-svg-in-next-js-with-typescript-88ebff26ce17

Comment: That's was the tutorial which I followed but turns out the problem isn't related to NextJS. The babel plugin to import the SVG isn't compatible with the import resolver.

Comment: Yes, try this plugin: https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a know compatibility issue between
> babel-plugin-module-resolver and babel-plugin-inline-react-svg

Refer to: [Next.js typescript import aliases with babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61241112/next-js-typescript-import-aliases-with-babel-plugin-module-resolver)

The PR to solve this problem isn't merged yet https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg/pull/17

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I just found is that the babel plugin does not work as good as the `@svgr/webpack` plugin for webpack.
If you use it and the `<svg />`s do not load as expected consider taking a look at
to Shifut Hossain's question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175445/cant-import-svg-into-next-js).
I saved me a lot of time! :)